# Floating circle using css3 or jquery or html5

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5-canvas, floating

I am trying to make a circle/bubble (50px x 50px) float within an area of about 150x150px. I want it to look organic; ideally not a simple up and down motion with easing. I would like it to appear to be floating naturally.

Cross browser compatibility is not paramount, just so long as it is static as a fallback that would be fine.

Any ideas/tutorials/jsfiddle's anyone can advise me to use?

Comment: I googled bubble HTML5 example and found a couple of good samples.  For instance:  http://hanswestman.se/files/html5_canvas_2.html.  The code can be found here:  http://hanswestman.se/2011/02/html5-animating-in-canvas/  a sample fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/9v3nu/

Comment: Processing.js maybe ? http://processingjs.org/

Comment: I would use TweenMaxJS and simply give it some boundaries, and a random number to tween to between those boundaries, this would look organic...

Comment: As long as we're just floating ideas about floating bubbles ;)  ...if you want to add realistic physics into the mix, check out **Box2d**.  If you set up 150px boundaries for your bubble float in and you lower their gravity to almost zero, your bubbles will have realistic physics.  Box2d has been ported to various languages, including javascript.